# Can FFT for prime $n$ be implemented as a product of $O(n\log(n))$ $2\times 2$ unitaries?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, computation-models, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

Consider normalized DFT (discrete Fourier transform) — a transform with input $x = (x_0,\dots,x_{n-1})$ and output $y=(y_0,\dots,y_{n-1})$ s.t.
$$y_j = \frac1{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{l=0}^{n-1} x_l \omega^{jl}, \tag{1}$$
where $\omega$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity (e.g. $\omega = e^{-2\pi i/n}$). It is described by a unitary matrix $F=F_n$ with elements $F_{jl} = \frac1{\sqrt{n}} \omega^{jl}$. We are looking for a decomposition
$$F_{jl} = P \tilde{A}_{m-1}\cdots\tilde{A}_0, \tag{2}$$
where $P$ can be any permutation matrix of our choice and each $\tilde{A}_k$ is a unitary matrix acting non-trivially only on 2 elements of a vector. That is, for every $k$ there is a pair $(r_{0k},r_{1k})$ of indices s.t. $(\tilde{A}_{k})_{ij}$ coincides with identity matrix except for 4 elements, which form a $2\times 2$ unitary matrix $A_k$:
$$ A_k = \begin{pmatrix}
(\tilde{A}_{k})_{r_{0k}r_{0k}} & (\tilde{A}_{k})_{r_{0k}r_{1k}} \\
(\tilde{A}_{k})_{r_{1k}r_{0k}} & (\tilde{A}_{k})_{r_{1k}r_{1k}}
\end{pmatrix}.$$
For example, if $A_k$ is $\frac1{\sqrt{2}} \left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, $n=5$, and $(r_{0k}, r_{1k}) = (1,4)$, then
$$ \tilde{A}_k = \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0&0\\0&1/\sqrt{2}&0&0&1/\sqrt{2}\\0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&1/\sqrt{2}&0&0&-1/\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}.$$

In other words, we use the model of computation where at each step $t$ one could pick 2 values $x_{r_{0t}}$ and $x_{r_{1t}}$ in the $x$ array and replace them with $A_{t} (x_{r_{0t}}, x_{r_{1t}})^T$. In particular, one is not allowed to use any memory (not even a single register) except for the $n$-element vector $x$, which needs to be transformed to $y$ in-place.

Let $m^*(n)$ be the minimal $m$ for which such a decomposition is possible. For example, $m^*(1)=0$, $m^*(2)=1$, $m^*(3)=3$, $m^*(4)=4$. The Cooley-Tukey algorithm has this form, so $m^*(n_1n_2)\leq m^*(n_1)n_2 + m^*(n_2)n_1$. Thus, if $n$ is a power of $2$ we have $m^*(n) \leq n\log_2(n)/2$, and if $n$ is a product of small primes $m^*(n) = O(n\log(n))$.

Is it also true that $m^*(n) = O(n\log(n))$ for prime $n$ (and, thus, for all $n$)?

---

**My research**: Here are some (failed) attempts to answer this question.

1. There is a bound $m^*(n) \leq n(n-1)/2$ based on the complex Givens decomposition as found in some implementations of the QR algorithm and in the implementation of [openfermion.circuits.bogoliubov_transform](https://quantumai.google/reference/python/openfermion/circuits/bogoliubov_transform).
2. A better bound $m^*(n) \leq (n-1)(n+3)/4$ can be obtained as follows. Let $H = H^{-1} = \frac1{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ be the $2\times 2$ Hadamard matrix and let $H_{\{j,l\}}$ be the unitary $n\times n$ which is identity except for $H$ inserted at the indices $\{j,l\}$. Let $P=I$ and $A_{m-1-k} = A_{k} = H_{\{1+k,n-1-k\}}$ for $k=0,\dots,\frac{n-1}{2}$ and $U=U^{-1}=A_0\cdots A_{(n-1)/2}$. It remains to decompose $\tilde{F} = U^{-1} F U^{-1}$. Note that if $j\leq \frac{n-1}{2}$ and $k > \frac{n-1}{2}$, then $\tilde{F}_{jl}=0$: e.g. for $j\neq0$ we have $\tilde{F}_{jl}=\frac{2^{-(n-1)/4}}{\sqrt{n}} ((\omega^{jl}+\omega^{-jl})-(\omega^{jl}+\omega^{-jl}))=0$. In other words, $\tilde{F}$ is block-diagonal with blocks of sizes $\frac{n+1}{2},\frac{n-1}{2}$. Applying the Givens decomposition to both blocks, we get
   $$m = n-1 + \sum_{\pm} \frac{(n\pm 1)(n\pm 1 - 2)}{8} = \frac{(n-1)(n+3)}{4}.$$
3. A commonly used algorithm for FFT for prime $n$ is Rader's algorithm. It first computes $y_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{l=0}^{n-1} x_{l}$ and then uses a generator $g$ of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_{n}^*$ to reduce the computation of $y_j$ for $j>0$ to convolution plus addition of $x_0$. The problem with adapting this algorithm to our case is that we are not allowed to use "extra" memory (to store both $x_0$ and $y_0$). Also, the function we are convolving with in Rader's algorithm has a non-unitary DFT, thus the convolution itself is non-unitary: e.g., the 0-th element of the DFT of $\{\exp(-2\pi i g^k/n)\}_{k=0,\dots,n-2}$ is $-1/\sqrt{n-1}$ and does not have an absolute value of 1.

**Motivation**:

1. In an abstract of ["A Lower Bound for Fourier Transform Computation in a Linear Model Over 2x2 Unitary Gates Using Matrix Entropy"](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=18357072408764174563), Nir Ailon considers "a layered linear circuit model restricted to unitary 2×2 gates" (the same computational model as described in this question) and states that "the well known FFT works in this model". This is certainly true for the Cooley-Tukey algorithm, but I do not know how to implement it efficiently in this computational model for large prime $n$.
2. An algorithm in this computational model [leads](https://quantumai.google/reference/python/openfermion/circuits/ffft) to an algorithm for [Fermionic Fourier Transform](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/52712/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-fermionic-fourier-transform) (with the same complexity if executed on a fully connected fault tolerant quantum computer and with $2^L$ multiplicative overhead if executed on a classical computer).

Comment: You may have a better chance of getting an answer at https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/ or https://mathoverflow.net/.

Comment: @orlp Notice that while the question has implications for the complexity of fermionic Fourier transform on quantum computers, the question itself is about a classical computational model: each $2\times 2$ unitary in the question is only allowed to modify 2 classical registers (as opposite to a quantum circuit, where a single $2\times 2$ unitary gate would modify all amplitudes).